# How to format date in moment js

Tags: angular, pipe, momentjs

How can we customize the date from moment js? I want to display only Ex: **Thu 10** of the month.
How can we achieve that using moment or pipe need your help.

app.component.html

```
<h2>{{ dateCtr.value | date }}</h2>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import {MomentDateAdapter, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS} from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import {DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE} from '@angular/material/core';

import _moment from 'moment';
// tslint:disable-next-line:no-duplicate-imports
import {default as _rollupMoment} from 'moment';

const moment = _rollupMoment || _moment;

// See the Moment.js docs for the meaning of these formats:
// https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/
export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'LL',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'LL',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  providers: [
    // `MomentDateAdapter` can be automatically provided by importing `MomentDateModule` in your
    // application's root module. We provide it at the component level here, due to limitations of
    // our example generation script.
    {
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useClass: MomentDateAdapter,
      deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS]
    },

    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS},
  ],
})

export class AppComponent  {

  dateCtr = new FormControl(moment());

  incrementDate(){
  this.dateCtr.setValue(moment(this.dateCtr.value).add(1, 'days').format());
 }

  decrementDate(){
  this.dateCtr.setValue(moment(this.dateCtr.value).subtract(1, 'days').format());
 }

}
```

pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

@Pipe({ name: 'mypipe' })
export class Mypipe implements PipeTransform {
  // adding a default value in case you don't want to pass the format then 'yyyy-MM-dd' will be used
  transform(date: Date | string, day: number, format: string = 'yyyy-MM-dd'): string {
    date = new Date(date);  // if orginal type was a string
    date.setDate(date.getDate() - day);
    return new DatePipe('en-US').transform(date, format);
  }
}
```

How can we customize the date from moment js? I want to display only Ex: **Thu 10** of the month.
How can we achieve that using moment or pipe need your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
step 1 : import { Datepipe } from "@angular/comman"; // import inside app.modules.ts

step 2: use
      <h2>{{ dateCtr.value | date: "EE d" }}</h2> 

instead of <h2>{{ dateCtr.value | date }}</h2>
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be done without momentJs. This is how I did it:
**Typescript:**

```
const days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
const date = new Date();
const dayName = this.days[this.date.getDay()];
const monthName = this.months[this.date.getMonth()];
```

**HTML:**

```
<p>{{ dayName }} {{ date | date:'dd' }} {{ monthName }} {{ date | date:'yyyy' }}</p>
```

**Output:**
Tuesday 08 October 2020

Answer (score 2):

Using moment you can achieve it by using this

```
moment(datavalue).format('ddd DD [of] MMMM')
```

I think this will solve your issue.